# R base vs plyr regression output

Tags: r, output, regression, plyr

I am using the `plyr` package to run regressions on panel data by SUBJECT and YEAR.  I would like to replicate the output from `plyr` using only R `base` functions.  In particular, the `plyr` package preserves the SUBJECT and YEAR variable names, but the `base` functions do not.  Is it possible to replicate the `plyr` output using only R `base` functions?  Below is an example of the code I have tried:

```
data <- data.frame(SUBJECT=c(rep('FISHER',10), rep('HUNTER',10)), YEAR=c(rep(2011,5), rep(2012,5), rep(2011,5), rep(2012,5)), y=rnorm(20), x=rnorm(20))
data
```

## Using only R `base` functions

```
with(data, t(sapply(split(data, list(SUBJECT,YEAR), drop=TRUE), function(x) { coef(lm(y ~ x, data = x)) })))
```

## Using `plyr` functions

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data, .(SUBJECT,YEAR), function(x) { coef(lm(y ~ x, data = x)) })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (`ix <- 1:2` would also work):

```
ix <- c("SUBJECT", "YEAR")
reg <- function(DF) cbind(  DF[1, ix],  t(coef(lm(y ~ x, DF)))  )
do.call(rbind, by(data, data[ix], reg))
```

which gives this:

```
  SUBJECT YEAR (Intercept)           x
1  FISHER 2011   0.8665496  0.25377389
2  HUNTER 2011   0.4954567  0.05370458
3  FISHER 2012   0.5280182  0.95038956
4  HUNTER 2012  -0.8319516 -0.04778639
```

Comment: Didn't notice you nearly identical response.  I have updated it with a few minor improvements.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, the lack of ending brackets is definitely easier on the eyes :p

Answer (score 1):

I generally use `plyr` for these kinds of tasks myself so I'm guessing there is a cleaner way to do this in base R, but here is one solution:

```
> runRegression <- function(v){
+   sub <- data[data$SUBJECT == v[1] & data$YEAR == v[2],]
+   coef(lm(y ~ x, data = sub))
+ }
> 
> cbind(unique(data[,c("SUBJECT","YEAR")]),t(apply(unique(data[,c("SUBJECT","YEAR")]),1,runRegression)))
   SUBJECT YEAR (Intercept)          x
1   FISHER 2011   0.3409430  0.2860310
6   FISHER 2012   0.1065906  0.5851614
11  HUNTER 2011  -0.3774422  0.9029407
16  HUNTER 2012   0.1697793 -0.5429523
```